# Is there a way to clone a specific tag from a git?

Tags: libgit2sharp

I was wondering if there was a way to clone a Git project by a specific tag ?
I'm trying to do a C# console that clone project by options, such as name, branch ...
But I can't find a way to clone it by a specific tag.
Does someone knows a way to do it ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Clone usually pulls in a full copy of the repository. You can switch to the proper tag after that, but that probably means you should create a new branch at that specific tag.